# Generate all sublists of a list in OCAML

Tags: list, ocaml

What I want to do is generating all sub-lists of a list in OCAML,
for example for

```
[1; 2; 3]
```

as a result I want to get this

```
[[1]; [2]; [3]; [1; 2]; [1; 3]; [2; 3]; [1; 2; 3]]
```

This is my approach so far:

```
let sublist l = 
  let rec aux i j max l2 =
    match l with 
    | [] -> l
    | h:t -> 
      if (i = max && j = max) then l2 
      else if (j < max ) then aux i j+1 [h]::tl  
      else aux i+1 i+1 l
  in 
  aux 0 0 (List.length l) []
```

Comment: (a) What about the empty list? I would expect to see it in the result, as it's a sublist of every list. (b) What if the input list looks like `['x'; 'q'; 'b']?

Comment: What specifically is the problem with the code you have? Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an divide and conquer approach: given a non-empty list, you get a list of all its sublists by removing its first element `x` and solving the problem for the remaining elements (via a recursion step).

When the recursive call returns, you combine this intermediate result with the element `x` you previously cut off: you have to return each of the sublist with `x` added in front of it and unmodified.

```
let rec sublists = function
  | []    -> [[]]
  | x::xs -> let ls = sublists xs in
               List.map (fun l -> x::l) ls @ ls;;
```

For your example input this computes:

> # sublists [1;2;3];;
>
> - : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [1; 2]; [1; 3]; [1]; [2; 3]; [2]; [3]; []]

The computed list can be sorted and filtered, depending on whether you want the empty list in the result or not.